# Asus ROG G750XJ not turning on after LCD screen replacement

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, lcd

Hope someone can answer my question to this particular problem.

I have a Asus ROG G750XJ which needed it's LCD screen replaced due to it being cracked. Long story short, I removed the damaged screen, booted the laptop, connected an external LCD screen via VGA (tried HDMI also which works fine too) all tested and working ok, so GPU is not the issue, shut the laptop down.

Called the local "laptop repair shop" they said they they have the screen in stock (I did provide all serial numbers, dimension etc for them to make sure the screen is a match). They said bring it in so we can connect the replacement and see if it works. They connected the screen, tried to turn it on, it wouldn't plus there was a scent of burning (you know the kind when you fry a motherboard component!) They told me the laptop doesn't work but I know for a fact that it did prior letting them connect the replacement.

I took the laptop back to the lab, disassembled it and found that the Super IO/Start Up chip has burn marks on it and one of the buck converters (Dual Synchronous, Step-Down Controller) is getting melting hot when connected to the power supply. No LED are being lit when connected to either battery or power supply, so it's safe to say those chips need replacing or a new motherboard.

SO MY QUESTION IS! Can connecting the incorrect screen or a faulty screen (Yes new doesn't mean it's in working order) burn out the SuperIO chip or damaged SMD components such as a buck converter??? Any definitive answer would be great and very much appreciated :) thank you in advance.

Chips in question are as follows
Buck converter: ti 51275
Super IO: ITE IT8585E, 1318-FXA, AC0YKA (comma means new line)

Comment: Of course a wrong screen could cause damage. It’s hard for us to answer your question. We don’t know anything about what the repair shop did, or what they hooked up to your computer. Screens are pretty standard anymore. Get the right resolution and plug them in. Usually not an issue even if it isn’t the correct match. But the cable from the screen to the motherboard IS proprietary. A wrong one would definitely cause issues.

Comment: The cable connecting the screen and motherboard is the factory flat cable, it was never removed. Only the 40pin connector that plugs into the LCD screen was removed from the old faulty screen and plugged into the the new screen, no other work was done, I witnessed them (service shop) plug the new screen in, the burning smell started and they said your laptop is faulty. So to answer your specific question, the "repair" shop didn't do anything other than connect a replacement screen to the end of the flat cable that was hanging from the plastic housing that houses the screen.